# Hudson Maven ${basedir} can't find dependency

Tags: java, maven, hudson

I have a created a maven repo in a directory called lib in the base of my project.
I can use maven to build this project and fetch dependencies from the repo in the lib directory. When I try to build this project with Hudson, Hudson can not find the dependencies in the lib repo.

Here are the relevant parts of the project pom:

```
      <dependency>
         <groupId>manitou</groupId>
         <artifactId>manitou.cxf.jar</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0</version>
      </dependency>

   </dependencies>

   <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>ErpClientsLibRepo</id>
      <url>file://${basedir}/lib</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

Here are the errors from Maven when ran from Hudson:

```
[INFO] o.h.m.e.h.MavenExecutionResultHandler - Build failed with exception(s)
[INFO] o.h.m.e.h.MavenExecutionResultHandler - [1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project DigabitERPClients: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.digabit:DigabitERPClients:jar:1.2.0: Failure to find manitou:manitou.cxf.jar:jar:1.0.0 in file:///opt/eng/hudson/jobs/20-DigabitJParent/workspace/DigabitErpClients/lib was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of ErpClientsLibRepo has elapsed or updates are forced
[DEBUG] Closing connection to remote
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project DigabitERPClients: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.digabit:DigabitERPClients:jar:1.2.0: Failure to find manitou:manitou.cxf.jar:jar:1.0.0 in file:///opt/eng/hudson/jobs/20-DigabitJParent/workspace/DigabitErpClients/lib was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of ErpClientsLibRepo has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Here is a dir listing at the path Maven (As ran by Hudson) seems to be looking at:

```
[root@vail lib]# cd /opt/eng/hudson/jobs/20-DigabitJParent/workspace/DigabitErpClients/lib
[root@vail lib]# ls
manitou
[root@vail lib]# ls manitou/
manitou.cxf.jar
[root@vail lib]#
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: If you are not using a repository manager start to use one and deploy those artifacts into the repository manager and hudson will be able to access them.

Answer (score 0):

I went into the hudson project and forced maven to update, now the build works :S